# CMD to bash script conversion semicolumn

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to convert a CMD script (.bat) into a .sh script on Linux side.

I did not find a proper documentation for instance for the following lines

```
set PATH="${PATH1}%;${PATH_NAME};"

another_script.bat -create "%LocalDestination%TEST;%LocalDestination%" -e %GenericEnvironementName% -d "%SettingsPath%/Env"
```

For the first one it is an export but I do not know it is like the if condition?

```
${PATH1}=${PATH_NAME}
export PATH=$PATH1
```

for the second one the expression
`"%LocalDestination%TEST;%LocalDestination%"` it's like an assignement? why we put the `%` at the end?

```
$LocalDestination$TEST = $LocalDestination
```

`%GenericEnvironementName%` will be `$GenericEnvironementName`
`%SettingsPath%/Env >>> $SettingsPath/Env?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Variables in dos bat files are delimited with `%`, before AND after.  So `%VAR%` is replaced by the value of `VAR`.
- `set PATH="${PATH1};${PATH_NAME};"` assigns the values of `PATH1` and `PATH_NAME` to variable `PATH`, separated by `;`.
- In Bash you would write: `export PATH="$PATH1;$PATH_NAME"`
- Therefore, yes, any variable referencing is bash is done with `$` before the variable name.  So `%TATA%` becomes `$TATA`.
- Example: `%SettingsPath%/Env` --> `${SettingsPath}/Env`

Comment: if `set PATH="${PATH1}%;${PATH_NAME};"` is batch, it's going to set `PATH` to that literal string (minus the `%` because those need to be doubled in order to be escaped) because only the `%variable%` syntax is valid (and `!variable!`, but that's outside the scope of this question).

Comment: Indeed, my mistake, I removed the `%`.  It should have read `set PATH="${PATH1};${PATH_NAME};"`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers set PATH="${PATH1}%;${PATH_NAME};" is batch, it's going to set PATH to that literal string (minus the % so my question is the value will be a concatenation of the 2? PATH="${PATH1};${PATH_NAME};" with a semicolumn after each variable? I'm not really sure...

Comment: Yes.  Each variable is replaced by its value, and concatenated with the next.  The `;` are not part of the variable names, so they are treated as text, and concatenated with the rest.  Ex. you could build a string like this: `${var1}sometext${var2}`.  The result would be the value of var1, sometext, the value of var2, all concatenated (i.e. "glued") together.